# Docker stack deploy rolling updates volume issue

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-registry, docker-swarm

I'm running docker for a production PHP-FPM/Nginx application, I want to use docker-stack.yml and deploy to a swarm cluster. Here's my file:

```
version: "3"
services:

app:
  image: <MYREGISTRY>/app
volumes:
   - app-data:/var/www/app
deploy:
  mode: global

php:
  image: <MYREGISTRY>/php
volumes:
   - app-data:/var/www/app
deploy:
  replicas: 2

nginx:
  image: <MYREGISTRY>/nginx
    depends_on:
      - php
  volumes:
    - app-data:/var/www/app
  deploy:
    replicas: 2
  ports:
    - "80:80"

volumes:
 app-data:
```

My code is in `app` container with image from my registry.

I want to update my code with `docker service update --image <MYREGISTRY>/app:latest` but it's not working the code is not changed.
I guess it uses the local volume `app-data` instead.

Is it normal that the new container data doesn't override volume data?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is the expected behavior. Named volumes are only initialized to the image contents when they are empty (the default state when first created). Updating the volume any time after that point would risk data loss from overwriting or deleting volume data that you explicitly asked to be preserved.

If you need the files to be updated with every new image, then perhaps they shouldn't be in a volume? If you do need these inside a volume, then you may need to create a procedure to update the volumes from the image, e.g. if this were a `docker run`, you could do:

```
docker run -v app-data:/target --rm <your_registry>/app cp -a /var/www/app/. /target/.
```

Otherwise, you can delete the volume, or simply remove all files from the volume, and restart your stack to populate it again.

Comment: Thanks for your response, indeed I think It shouldn't be in a volume but how can I share the code from `app` to `php` and `nginx` without a volume?
I also thought of the procedure to update the volume, I guess that's my best option for now

Comment: I'm a bit confused why you have both an nginx and a php container and what purpose the app container provides other than your volume. Seems like it should be simplified to a single container that wouldn't even need a volume.

Comment: You're right the only purpose of the app container is having the code and provide volume.
A single container for all is more difficult to update (If I just want to update the code for example) and I think it's better to version code only image.

Comment: For me it would be easier to build a single image based on the php+apache image that is available as part of the official repo. Add your single layer of code on top of that. That eliminates both of the other containers (nginx would be redundant) and allows you to do rolling upgrades and other versioning with that container.

Comment: I've been struggling with this exact issue, this is the easiest and smartest solution: make a single container. Guaranteed working solution.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue that I have app and nginx containers sharing the same volume. My current solution having a deploy script which runs

```
docker service update --mount-add mount service
```

for app and nginx after docker stack deploy. It will force to update the volume for app and nginx containers.